# how to avoid ActionController::ParameterMissing when replacing a rails simple_form form submitted through ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to update the following form submitted through ajax:

```
<div id="tournament_new_registration_form">
  <%= simple_form_for(@registration, remote: true, html: { class: 'form-inline', id: 'registration_form' }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :name %>

    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-warning', id: 'registration_form_submit' %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The response in case of errors is the following (the partial is exactly the form above):

```
$("#tournament_new_registration_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form') %>");

$('#tournament_new_registration_form').on('click', '#registration_form_submit', function() {
    $('form#registration_form').submit();
});
```

The first submission works well and I benefit of the errors management system provided by simple_form.

The issue is that when I click a second times on the submit button I get an exception: ActionController::ParameterMissing at /registrations. The root cause is quite simple; no parameter are sent.

I suspect a DOM issue, how could I make the replaced form working?